# What's the importance of the email address in the DNS SOA lookup?

Tags: domain-name-system, security, bind

Is there a real importance in this, except to publish the email address of the person responsible for some DNS zone?

In our BIND configuration, we put a mailling list as the responsible for our domain, but we are usure if this is good practice or not.

Area there any kind of services that rely on this email address? In the worse case, can an invalid email in this field compromise our DNS authority?

Comment: We use the address for our helpdesk ticketing system, but this is a good question.

Comment: A mailing list is a good idea in terms of continuity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) section 3.3.13 says:

> ```
> RNAME           A <domain-name> which specifies the mailbox of the
>                 person responsible for this zone.
> ```

That's all.

Someone out there on the Internet might use this address to contact you regarding issues with your DNS, so it should be a valid address which routes messages sent to it to the right people.

Best practice for this is to use a role address such as hostmaster ([RFC 2142](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142) section 7) which can then be routed to the right person, mailing list, ticket system, etc.

Comment: I would say: *Someone out there on the Internet might use this address to **spam** you*